# Prevent ERC721 metadata from being updated

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-721, nft

I have a ERC721 token and the TokenURI gets set to a IPFS JSON link. The JSON contains metadata such as name, color, image ect about the NFT.

The problem is I have a function which allows the TokenURI to be updated, but how can I prevent the 'name' field being edited?

Is there another way to just store the 'name' metadata? maybe somewhere in the ERC721 contract?

Heres my contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v3.4/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract SampleNFTContract is ERC721 {

constructor () public ERC721 ("NFTTest1", "NFT1"){
}

// mint nft
function createNFT(uint256 tokenID, string memory ipfsLink) external {

_safeMint(msg.sender, tokenID);

_setTokenURI(tokenID, ipfsLink);

}

// update ipfsLink
function updateURL(uint256 tokenID, string memory ipfsLink) external {

// check if owner
require(_isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenID), "Only owner can update");

_setTokenURI(tokenID, ipfsLink);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

See: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721#simple-summary

```
/// @title ERC-721 Non-Fungible Token Standard, optional metadata extension
/// @dev See https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721
///  Note: the ERC-165 identifier for this interface is 0x5b5e139f.
interface ERC721Metadata /* is ERC721 */ {
    /// @notice A descriptive name for a collection of NFTs in this contract
    function name() external view returns (string _name);

    /// @notice An abbreviated name for NFTs in this contract
    function symbol() external view returns (string _symbol);

    /// @notice A distinct Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) for a given asset.
    /// @dev Throws if `_tokenId` is not a valid NFT. URIs are defined in RFC
    ///  3986. The URI may point to a JSON file that conforms to the "ERC721
    ///  Metadata JSON Schema".
    function tokenURI(uint256 _tokenId) external view returns (string);
}
```

You can use extra fields for name and symbol.

Comment: This is a per-contract name, not a per-token name. I believe the asker is seeking the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are looking to have a contract-enforced way to specify that the metadata will include a certain name.

Of course you will not achieve this goal if the contract allows arbitrary URLs linking to arbitrary JSON which can have any `name` set.

Here are some options.

1. **Give up.** Do not put the name in the `ERC721Metadata`, instead, create a proprietary `tokenName(uint256)` function which you manage separately.
2. **Use [ERC2477 (DRAFT)](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2477).** This allows you to have some control over the metadata to ensure the name is as you want it. Note that this will require you to implement a zero-knowledge proof or a JSON parser on-chain which validates the new metadata.
3. **Use 0xcert Framework.** The 0xcert framework is specifically designed to provide metadata integrity for ERC-721 tokens, it uses a different hashing technique (Merkle tree) which is compatible with your use case. But it requires you to use the same schema across metadata versions.